# powershell. blank screenshot taken by screept in RDB machine

Tags: c#, powershell, screenshot

I have a script which takes screenshot in a webpage. Then it calls a console application to check weather it have red pixels if yes then mail it. But I want to run it 24×7 in a RDB machine the issue is  its taking blank screenshot when ever i lock my computer. why it is happening . It is running on remote computer and It is not in lock state. But whenever I minimize RDB window or lock it it take wrong screen shot. is there any solution to my problem.

I tried send key press after every 1 minute but again system got lock anyway. I can't disable screen lock time. What I the logic behind blank screenshot ? Is there any solution? Except screen lock disable.

Comment: Can you post the script and how you have it configured to run on the remote machine?

Comment: it is in my office and i cant copy or mail from there. but i got script from here only (stackover flow) it is simple it open IE full scree. then nevigate to URL . wait for 5 sec to get it load . then scrolls down . take a snapshoot. then close the IE . i am running it via tasksheduler . it run perfect when i run it but after some time it start taking blank screen shoot. again the system is RDB . iwin system i also looged using citrx but problem is same . i tried with auto keypress but it is not working anyway sceen got lock

Answer (score 1):

My guess it has nothing to do with the screen lock time but the fact, that if you log on to a windows machine via remote desktop, the built in graphics card is swapped with a virtual one that is optimized for usage of rdp.

As statet [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> On the server, RDP uses its own video driver to render display output
>   by constructing the rendering information into network packets by
>   using RDP protocol and sending them over the network to the client. On
>   the client, RDP receives rendering data and interprets the packets
>   into corresponding Microsoft Windows graphics device interface (GDI)
>   API calls.

So one possible reason could be that you start your application, switch the graphics card by disconnecting the remote session and the started application looses its handle (meaning it is unable to handle the change of the graphics card).

Have you tried starting the application by using e.g. a scheduled task and without starting in the remote session? If not I would suggest to try that.

Comment: yes the script is taking screen shoot every hour. it run on my RDB machine . i only use my physical machine to log in to RDB . i am using citrix tool to log in also but problem is after 15 to 20 minutes it start saving 2KBS blank screenshoot don know why . i am pressing num key via powershell. i can see num key led switching but anyhow it got locked .is there any solution .

Comment: It is very hard to solve a problem like this without specific details. Have you tried taking screenshots with another tool and does this work? Maybe the script is buggy... Can you post your code/script which is used for taking the screenshots please?